# file is not defined, python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to create an xml file. THis is the program 
 I am using python 3.5 and as IDE pycharm. Do I miss a library? Or something?
Or is it the IDE what not correct is?

but I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I have this:

```
import datetime
import random
import time

def main():

 # Write an XML file with the results
   file = open("ListAccessTiming.xml","w")

   file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n')

file.write('<Plot title="Average List Element Access Time">\n')


xmin = 1000
xmax = 200000

  # Record the list sizes in xList and the average access time within
 # a list that size in yList for 1000 retrievals.
xList = []
yList = []

for x in range(xmin, xmax+1, 1000):

 xList.append(x)

 prod = 0




 lst = [0] * x

 # let any garbage collection/memory allocation complete or at least
 # settle down
 time.sleep(1)

 # Time before the 1000 test retrievals
 starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

 for v in range(1000):
 # Find a random location within the list
 # and retrieve a value. Do a dummy operation
 # with that value to ensure it is really retrieved.
  index = random.randint(0,x-1)
 val = lst[index]
 prod = prod * val
 # Time after the 1000 test retrievals
 endtime = datetime.datetime.now()

 # The difference in time between start and end.
 deltaT = endtime - starttime

 # Divide by 1000 for the average access time
 # But also multiply by 1000000 for microseconds.
 accessTime = deltaT.total_seconds() * 1000

 yList.append(accessTime)

 file.write(' <Axes>\n')
 file.write(' <XAxis min="’+str(xmin)+’" max="’+str(xmax)+’">List Size</XAxis>\n')
 file.write(' <YAxis min="’+str(min(yList))+’" max="’+str(60)+’">Microseconds</YAxis>\n')
 file.write(' </Axes>\n')
 file.write(' <Sequence title="Average Access Time vs List Size" color="red">\n')

 for i in range(len(xList)):
  file.write('<DataPoint x="’+str(xList[i])+’" y="’+str(yList[i])+’"/>\n')

 file.write('</Sequence>\n')

 # This part of the program tests access at 100 random locations within a list
 # of 200,000 elements to see that all the locations can be accessed in
 # about the same amount of time.
 xList = lst
 yList = [0] * 200000

 time.sleep(2)

 for i in range(100):
  starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
 index = random.randint(0,200000-1)
 xList[index] = xList[index] + 1
 endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
 deltaT = endtime - starttime
 yList[index] = yList[index] + deltaT.total_seconds() * 1000000

 file.write('<Sequence title="Access Time Distribution" color="blue">\n');

 for i in range(len(xList)):
  if xList[i] > 0:
   file.write('<DataPoint x="’+str(i)+’" y="’+str(yList[i]/xList[i])+’"/>\n')
file.write('</Sequence>\n')
file.write('</Plot>\n')
file.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like indentation is way off. `file` only exists in the function's scope

Comment: You should really use 4 spaces for your indentation. Either way, `main` is the function that defines `file`, before `main` is executed `file` doesn't exist as a name and after its executed it only exists inside the function's scope. When python encounters `file.write('<Plot title="Average List Element Access Time">\n')` it will complain since that name still hasn't been defined. You should probably define `file` in the global i.e top level scope.

Comment: @ Jim.Thank you for your reply. But what I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is all about indentation.  Blocks are defined by indentation.  You define a function `main()` and start its indented block...

```
def main():

 # Write an XML file with the results
   file = open("ListAccessTiming.xml","w")

   file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n')
```

And then you *exit* that indented block and try to use the `file` variable:

```
file.write('<Plot title="Average List Element Access Time">\n')
```

If you are to have the `main()` function do all your work, then it all needs to be properly indented within the `main()` function (which, by the way, you never call):  (This code has also been reformatted to use a python-normal 4-space indentation)

```
def main():

    # Write an XML file with the results
    file = open("ListAccessTiming.xml","w")

    file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n')

    file.write('<Plot title="Average List Element Access Time">\n')

    # ... (rest of your code here) ...

    # let any garbage collection/memory allocation complete or at least
    # settle down
    time.sleep(1)

main()
```

If you want to do the work in the module directly, don't bother defining the `main()` function, and properly indent your code for use at the module level (meaning the top level statements have no indentation):

```
# Write an XML file with the results
file = open("ListAccessTiming.xml","w")

file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n')

file.write('<Plot title="Average List Element Access Time">\n')

# ... (rest of your code here) ...

# let any garbage collection/memory allocation complete or at least
# settle down
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

tab problem !

file variable is not into def main section

def main and file have not indentation

also your main is not called in your tool's